# Conjunctions in MATCH clause?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do you `or` conditions rather then `and`? Example below:

```
START user = node({id})
MATCH
(user)-[:follows]->(followed),
(follower)-[:follows]->(user)
RETURN user, followed, follower
```

What I want to get back is: `user`, regardless of whether anyone follows her or whether she follows anyone. All `followers`, if any. All `followed` if any.

The query above acts as if it was an `and`. If if `user` follows no one, or no one follows the user, nothing is returned.

---

Here's something else I've tried, but I'm getting a syntax error on it:

```
start a = node(40663) 
with a, a as b 
match (b)-[:follows]->(c) 
with b, a as d 
(e)-[:follows]->(d) 
return a, c, e;
```

The error:

```
SyntaxException: string matching regex `$' expected but `(' found

Think we should have better error message here? Help us by sending this query to cypher@neo4j.org.

Thank you, the Neo4j Team.

"start a = node(40663) with a, a as b match (b)-[:follows]->(c) with b, a as d (e)-[:follows]->(d) return a, c, e"
                                                                               ^
```

Regardless of this error, the reduced query (with only one `with`) returns zero results, so that doesn't seem to be the way to do it either.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do:

```
START user = node({id})
MATCH
p1 = (user)-[:follows]->(followed),
p2 = (follower)-[:follows]->(user)
RETURN user, followed, follower
```

alternatively:

```
START user = node({id})
MATCH (user)-[:follows]->(f)
WITH user, collect(f) as followed 
MATCH (f)-[:follows]->(user)
RETURN user, followed, collect(f) as follower
```

Comment: The first one is really odd. Can you explain a bit? Why do I need these stray variables (are they even variables?), I mean, `p1` and `p2`. This still doesn't quite explain the semantic of the comma. Does it act like `and`, a strict `and` or does it short-circuit? Re' the second query: it returns the correct number of followed / followers, no duplicates. Could you explain why were there duplicates in my original query?

Comment: @wvxvw Basically there's a match for every unique combination of user, follwed, and follower. However since he's using COLLECT(f), the followed and follower nodes are all grouped into separate arrays.  So the unique combination is aggregated so you only have one user per row.

Comment: @LameCoder sorry, you've lost me completely. What question were you trying to answer?

Comment: @wvxvw You asked a question about the second query.  The duplicates in your original query are there because you are returning user, followed, follower.  If you have user U and followers (f1, f2) and followed (F1, F2) you would get results like:  U, f1, F1 / U, f1, F2 / U, f2, F1 / U, f2, F2.  Since he is collecting all of the followed and follower nodes into arrays, you only have one row per user with no duplication.

Comment: @LameCoder sorry, but it's a negative, both times. This is not the result I'm getting and my code isn't different in that how many arrays I get back from the query :/ You misunderstood the problem. I only get duplicates when the user appears to be both the followed and the follower, but the user doesn't follow herself.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I could solve this one using something like this:

```
start a = node(40663)
match (a)-[?:follows]->(b), (c)-[?:follows]->(a) 
return a, b, c;
```

But if there's a better way, don't hesitate to tell!

Answer (score 0):

match (c)<-[?:follows]-(a)-[?:follows]->(b)
should also work

EDIT:
Alternatively

```
START user = node({id})
MATCH user--m 
WHERE user-[:follows]->m 
OR user<-[:followed]-m 
RETURN user  ,m
```

Comment: Second variant isn't equivalent: I need those who follow `user` and those whom `user` follows in separate bags. There's more difficult to understand issue which both applies to your first variant and my variant alike. If `user` follows herself, then she will be listed twice in every list (which is wrong by all accounts, she follows herself only once and once alone). So I had to replace `a, collection(distinct b), collection(distinct c)` in the return clause. But I still can't tell whether it is a bug, or there's some logic behind it.